# Set project name in StackBlitz

Tags: angular

When I create a new project at https://stackblitz.com/ the name is auto-generated and looks something like this https://angular-h9csji.stackblitz.io. However, I've seen other projects where the names are more user-friendly (eg. https://angular-material-hello.stackblitz.io). Is it possible to customize the project name or update it in StackBlitz?

Answer (score 9):

The project title is used as both sub-domain App URL in the Preview, and as the app folder name in browser address bar. This can be edited to make it more user-friendly:

1. Edit by clicking the pencil icon beside the title top-left of the editor:
   [image: StackBlitz Title - Edit icon]
2. Save by pressing return or clicking the save icon. A spinning icon will be displayed while waiting for confirmation of the change:
   [image: StackBlitz Title - Save icon]
3. Note it must unique across StackBlitz to be saved:
   [image: StackBlitz duplicate title warning]

The Share options drop-down also indicate the way the title is used. A copy-to-clipboard button is provided on the right:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the name edit functionality at the left top corner to rename your project.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

After the update of stackblitz, we can change the URL slug of a project's in stackblitz under settings.

1. Click on settings icon as shown in the below image.
2. Click on pencil icon to edit the URL slug

[image]

Or else you can also edit in this way.
[image]